# Gram Schmidt Process in Diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I have to find a matrix P that orthogonally diagonalizes matrix A.
where

```
A= 4 2 
   2 4
```

I have found the eigen values and eigen vectors.

```
first eigen value= 2
eigen vector is (-1,1)

second eigen value= 6
eigen vector is (1,1)
```

but i am stuck here as i dont know how to proceed further using Gram Schmidt process.
Please help !

Comment: Why insist on Gram-Schmidt if you don't need it? For a symmetric matrix with distinct eigenvalues, any basis of eigenvectors is automatically orthogonal. You would only need Gram-Schmidt if there were a multiple eigenvalue (with eigenspace of dimension greater than $1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already found the eigenvectors and it turns out they are orthogonal. Now in order to find an orthonormal basis, you just have to divide the vectors by their norms. Then , you would get an orthonormal basis of vectors. The matrix can then be easily constructed.